# Why is my sqlite table filesize 10x bigger than expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, filesize

I have a 4GB text file with about 12 million lines. Each line is a pipe-separated (|) list of field values for an entity. There are about 20 fields per line for an entity.

I insert the data into a sqlite table with Python and the table is about 35GB, which is ridiculous.  So what am I doing wrong?

My table schema is

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{}' (
    Entity VARCHAR(255), 
    FieldName VARCHAR(255), 
    Value VARCHAR(255), 
    Code VARCHAR(255), 
    PermissionID VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY(Symbol, FieldName, ExchangeCode, PermissionID)
    )
```

So for example entity BOB in the text file will have a line like:

```
BOB|AX|33|45|23.2|47|65.3|.....|65|2019-10-23|
```

Note first 3 entries are `ENTITY|code|PermissionID`

And in the table would look like

```
ENTITY FieldName Value      Code PermissionID
BOB    45        23.3       AX   33
BOB    47        65.3       AX   33
...  
BOB    65       2019-10-23  AX   33
```

I am just reading the lines and splitting by pipe and inserting into this table and it gets huge for some reason. I know it is a lot of rows but if the text file is 4GB how can a table be almost 10x bigger??

Comment: I'm not offering this as a reason for the bloat, nor will I guarantee that it will reduce the size, but try [vacuuming](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) (i.e. condensing, compacting) the database after all the inserts.  If all that you do is successive inserts without edits, then it likely won't change much, but its worth trying.

Comment: One is a file, one is a database. There will be all sorts of overhead, plus lots of spare space to speed updates in future. While it is bigger, this should be more than offset by the speed of update (other than simple appends) and read operations. A compress operation of some sort (whatever that is in sqllite) might improve the size.

Comment: Sorry for being nit-picky, but the table schema is contradictory.  There are columns in the primary key that are not even defined in the schema.  Are you actually inserting all 20 fields, or only the 5 that you show in the schema and example data?

Comment: TomC's comment is a good general answer for any database.  But in particular, your primary key includes many columns, so those columns must essentially be stored twice... once with the row data (like all the other data) and once in the sorted index.  Also, each column probably takes about the same amount of overhead on average, but since you are storing very few characters per column, the overhead-to-column length will not be very efficient.  If you do not need all columns for queries, etc., perhaps you could leave some values concatenated together in strings for later separation.

Comment: Finally, see https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

Comment: [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) should always be considered if using a composite primary key.

Comment: Hi, Youre right my schema was contradictorg, Symbol in the primary key should be Entity and exchangeCode =Code. Yes I am inserting all fields present on the text file line into the DB, for all lines (12 million lines) with about 20 field value pairs per line, possibly 30. This DB isn't for long term storage in fact I just need the tables to make my query to get stats on something then i can delete the table immediately, but it being more than 10GB or so isnt acceptable so I may have to come up with another method of doing what I want